# __vite_ssr_import_1__.Client is not a constructor Error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia, appwrite

I am developing a simple app to showcase CRUD operations with Appwrite and Nuxt 3 (Release Candidate 11). The source code to the same can be found [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/workout-buddy).

I am using the landing page of the app (`index.vue`) for simple redirection i.e. if the `account` exits in the `accountStore`, I want to redirect the user to `/workouts` route, else ask them to login by redirection to the `/login` route.

The problem I am facing is when I am landing on the `index.vue` page (with no user session in progress in Appwrite), I am still getting redirected to `/workouts` route, instead of the `/login` route. I presume the reason for the same is the following error that is being logged in the console.
[image: Error]

I need help in figuring out from where is the error message originating and how to possibly remedy it.

Here is my public github repo: https://github.com/EshaanAgg/workout-buddy

Comment: Hi, do you mind sharing some of the files written down in the stacktrace that we can see in your screenshot?

Comment: Hey @kissu! You can check them out [here](https://github.com/EshaanAgg/workout-buddy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a bug with Nuxt 3 or Vite since Nuxt 3 is currently only a release candidate.

Also, in my opinion, Server Side Rendering (SSR) always complicates things so much. It doesn't look like you're using SSR, so you could possibly update your nuxt.config.ts to disable SSR:

```js
{
   // ... other stuff
   ssr: false
}
```

Comment: Quite a long shot and quite drastic solution, especially when you can disable that locally or even import some code on client-side only (locally). I don't recommend that one.

Comment: SSR is of course more complex for quite a decent amount of (good) reasons, but fallback'ing to an SPA is probably not the way to go.

Comment: Tried disabling `ssr` but still the error persists.

Comment: @EshaanAggarwal of course, the solution is quite unrelated to the issue.

Comment: @EshaanAggarwal, did you clean/rebuild after? The error went away for me 

Comment: I did, but still the error persists.

Comment: Update: Performed a hard reset by deleting the local copy of the repository, and recloning it. Now in the latest commit, disabling `ssr` gets rid of the errors, but with it the error persists.